# Temporarily disable double buffering in Java graphics applet

Tags: java, graphics, applet

is there an easy way to disable double buffering in a java applet if necessary?
I have a java applet that displays and animates a musical score so I needed it double buffered. However for teaching purposes I need to print this applet. The problem is that before I added buffering the output to the printer was vector based so I could make it as big as I wanted and it would look smooth (and also use the cheaper type of black ink!) but with the double buffering the output is of course an image, and a fairly low res one at that!

Basically I need the same applet to **use double buffering when it is called with the "display_tune" parameter** but to **draw straight to graphics with vector output when it's called with the "view_tune" parameter.**

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could try by doing something like

```
yourComponent.setDoubleBuffered(false);
// your print code
yourComponent.setDoubleBuffered(true);
```

the method is declared in `JComponent`. I used this solution to export a PNG from a [Jung](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) graph and it worked. I'm not sure if Jung overrides that method inside their components to a different thing but there's not hurt in trying..

Comment: Thanks to both of you for replying, you both seem to be referring to the same thing so I found some info http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-Printing.html on double buffering. My experience with java is limited. I am using an offscreen image, so instead of g2d.drawLine() etc I'm writing offscreenImage.drawLine(). I assume this is not the standard double buffering you are referring to? Is there a simple way of just renaming "g2d" to "offscreenImage" for when print version of the applet is being used?

Answer (score 2):

You should globally disable double buffering, not just for one component. Swing has something called a [RepaintManager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/RepaintManager.html). It allows you to enable and disable double buffering.